# prompt() in wicket components

Tags: java, javascript, wicket

I try to find pattern how to return 'prompt()' result in java like http://www.mysticcoders.com/blog/wicket-ajax-confirmation-modal-window/ (but in this case author using 'confirm' instead of 'prompt' and doesn't return anything from javascript). Now I am using hidden field in form and update this field before submit, but maybe you know how to solve this problem more elegant (for example using AJAX components in wicket). Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want so submit the prompted value within your form, your hidden field approach looks adequate to me. If you want to call some Wicket code on the server with the prompted value independently of the form submission, see [How do I call Java code from JavaScript code in Wicket?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/162911/how-do-i-call-java-code-from-javascript-code-in-wicket)